# 'far cry' vs. 'long haul'

Tags: meaning, expressions

In the test below, *Option 3* is the correct answer;

> The ---------- began at 5 A.M and they reached the peak of the
>   mountain at noon.
>
> 1.second nature
>
> 2.far cry
>
> 3.long haul
>
> 4.rolling stone

I wonder why the 2nd option can't fill the gap.

**What's the difference between 'long haul' and 'far cry'?**

---

The respected entries in merriam-webster:

- [far cry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/far%20cry)
- [long haul](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long%20haul)

Answer (score 1):

A "far cry" means (as per dictionary) a "long distance".  But in this exercise you need a phrase that means "a long *journey*".  The phrase "a far cry" doesn't suggest you are actually going to travel.

"A long haul" does mean a "journey that takes a long time" and so fits here.

This isn't a very good example, because both these phrases are not usually used literally about distances or journeys.  Instead they are used metaphorically, to mean "take a long time" and "be very different"

> Rewriting the database software is big job, but we have programmers who are in it for the long haul.  (they will work on the job for a long time.)
>
> HTML is a far cry from a compiled language like C. (The two things are very different from each other.)